# Boost DEBUG_NEW macro issue with MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, mfc

Only including **<boost/filesystem/path.hpp>**

I get the error:

```
C:\boost\boost_1_83_0\boost\system\detail\error_code.hpp(179,20): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'd2_'
```

Commenting the following line I can compile correctly.

```
::new( d2_ ) std::error_code( ec );
```

This happens using *msvc2019* compiling with *C++14 ISO*.
It's definitely something related to the **DEBUG_NEW** macro.
Visual C++ uses this macro in its Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) which I am currently using but I can't figure out how to fix this conflict.

Same issue at:

```
C:\boost\boost_1_83_0\boost\system\detail\error_category_impl.hpp(131,16): error C2059: syntax error: 'static_cast'
```

on this line:

```
 ::new( static_cast<void*>( stdcat_ ) ) boost::system::detail::std_category( this, system::detail::id_wrapper<0>() );
```

**Possible solution:**
This way I can bypass it:

```
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#pragma pop_macro("new")
```

Comment: And this is why macros are evil.

Comment: `#undef DEBUG_NEW`

Comment: use std::filesystem ... it was added to C++ 7 years ago.